# How can I isolate and carry a piece of a variable string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, oop, session, scripting, rdp

I'm creating a script to automate Shadow Session RDP, but I keep getting thrown this error message:

`Invalid connection file (/shadow@{ID=6; SessionName=console; Type=; UserName=jdoe;
 ComputerName=192.168.255.17; State=Active}[0].Id) specified`

Now, the specific character to make this script work is to get only the number from `ID=`, in this case the number 6 representing the session to shadow, to be placed in the `/shadow:` parameter, i.e. `/shadow:6`.

Here is the PowerShell script below (Function credit to PoSh Wolf/Anthony Howell):

```
Function Get-ActiveSessions{
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Name
        ,
        [switch]$Quiet
    )
    Begin{
        $return = @()
    }
    Process{
        If(!(Test-Connection $Name -Quiet -Count 1)){
            Write-Error -Message "Unable to contact $Name. Please verify its network connectivity and try again." -Category ObjectNotFound -TargetObject $Name
            Return
        }
        If([bool](([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match "S-1-5-32-544")){ #check if user is admin, otherwise no registry work can be done
            #the following registry key is necessary to avoid the error 5 access is denied error
            $LMtype = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine
            $LMkey = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server"
            $LMRegKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($LMtype,$Name)
            $regKey = $LMRegKey.OpenSubKey($LMkey,$true)
            If($regKey.GetValue("AllowRemoteRPC") -ne 1){
                $regKey.SetValue("AllowRemoteRPC",1)
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            }
            $regKey.Dispose()
            $LMRegKey.Dispose()
        }
        $result = qwinsta /server:$Name
        If($result){
            ForEach($line in $result[1..$result.count]){ #avoiding the line 0, don't want the headers
                $tmp = $line.split(" ") | ?{$_.length -gt 0}
                If(($line[19] -ne " ")){ #username starts at char 19
                    If($line[48] -eq "A"){ #means the session is active ("A" for active)
                        $return += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                            "ComputerName" = $Name
                            "SessionName" = $tmp[0]
                            "UserName" = $tmp[1]
                            "ID" = $tmp[2]
                            "State" = $tmp[3]
                            "Type" = $tmp[4]
                        }
                    }Else{
                        $return += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                            "ComputerName" = $Name
                            "SessionName" = $null
                            "UserName" = $tmp[0]
                            "ID" = $tmp[1]
                            "State" = $tmp[2]
                            "Type" = $null
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }Else{
            Write-Error "Unknown error, cannot retrieve logged on users"
        }
    }
    End{
        If($return){
            If($Quiet){
                Return $true
            }
            Else{
                Return $return
            }
        }Else{
            If(!($Quiet)){
                Write-Host "No active sessions."
            }
            Return $false
        }
    }
}

$IP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the IP address of the remote device: ' 

$activeSession = Get-ActiveSessions $IP

Mstsc.exe /shadow:$activeSession[0].Id /v:$IP /control /NoConsentPrompt /prompt
```

Any help is appreciated, as I'm new to PowerShell. Thank you!

Comment: So you want to read text from a file and use specific parts of it to build a command. Is that right? If so, post an example of file that contains the bits you want to use.

Comment: No, I'd like to get the session ID number that powershell pulls from the qwinsta/user session query and places into an object/string, ex. ID = 6, and just pull the number itself to place into the last line for the /shadow: parameter.

Comment: Something like `$line = 'blah blah ID = 6 more blah'; if ($line -match 'ID\s*=\s*(\d+)') { $id = $matches[1] }` then? Show us the whole example string. I'll bet the rest of the values can be had by a simple regex aswell instead of relying on string position.

Comment: `/shadow:$activeSession[0].Id` -> `/shadow:$($activeSession[0].Id)`

Comment: I would recommend editing your question, then, to more accurately reflect what you are asking.

Comment: Actually Mathias got the correct answer and made it work. Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen !